# C to assembly call convention 32bit vs 64bit

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, x86-64

I have been following the excellent book Programming Ground Up, wanting to learn assembly. Although not in the book at this point, I wanted to call my assembly function from C. on a 32 bit machine, this works as is when working from the book.

What I do here is storing the first argument in `%ebx` and the second in `%ecx`.

```
.type power, @function
.globl power
power:
    pushq   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $4, %esp

    movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
```

I compile this (and the rest of the function) into an object file, create a main.c, where I prototype the function and call it, something like this:

```
int power(int b, int x);
int a = power(2, 1);
```

However, when I compile this on a 64 bit machine, I get some very unexpected results. I modified the obvious, like the fact that `%esp` and `%ebp` needs to be replaced with `%rsp` and `%rbp`, but digging with GDB reveals that the arguments are nowhere to be found on the stack!

Checking out what happens by using the `-S` option to GCC I can see that instead of pushing the variables on the stack, GCC stores the arguments in registers.

```
 movl $1, %esi
 movl $2, %edi
 call power
```

On the 32 bit machine, it does what I expect and push the arguments on the stack:

```
 movl $1, 4(%esp)
 movl $2, (%esp)
 call power
```

Now what is going on here? Why does GCC pass the arguments in registers on 64 bit and on the stack on 32 bit? This is very confusing! And I can't find any mention on this anywhere. Is there anyone who can enlighten me on this situation?

Comment: x64 calling conventions are different to x86 ones. In most cases, due to the extra registers, the first four arguments are passed in registers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

64-bit C calling convention is: %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9

See full description here:
["System V Application Binary Interface: AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement" http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160315222117/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf)

3.2 Function Calling Sequence

When I learned the same topic, I made small C programs with required functions, compiled them in 64 bit compiler and read the Assembly code produced by C compiler. C/C++ compiler can be used like kind of Assembly reference.

Comment: I skimmed through that exact document, but I studied it more closely now, and it's all there, and it makes totally sense now. Thanks!

Comment: As for your edit: Yes, that is how I try to do it as well. Modifying the assembly function to work was no problem, and observing what the compiler does is no problem either, the problem was that I did not understand the rules for this behavior. But the document you linked to was the perfect answer for that.

Comment: As a note, Windows uses a different ABI - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx with just RCX, RDX, R8, R9 for arguments.

Comment: Answer was just edited about 2 hours ago. Note - Microsoft has multiple ABI's for 32 bit mode, one of which is `fastcall` , which uses ECX and EDX for the first two arguments.