# Calling printf from inline ASM (X64)

Tags: c, linux

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){
    char *fmt = "%s";
    char *s = "Hello world!\n";

//gcc -m32 test.c
#ifdef __i386__
    int32_t ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "push %1\n\t"
        "push %2\n\t"
        "movl $2, %%eax\n\t"
        "call printf\n\t"
        "movl %0, %%eax"
        : "=r" (ret)
        : "r" (s), "r" (fmt)
        :
    );
#endif

//gcc -m64 test.c
#ifdef __x86_64__
    int64_t ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "push %1\n\t"
        "push %2\n\t"
        "movq $2, %%rax\n\t"
        "call printf\n\t"
        "movq %0, %%rax"
        : "=r" (ret)
        : "r" (s), "r" (fmt)
        :
    );
#endif

    return ret;
}
```

The x86 version works as expected, but the x64 version segfaults. Why is it segfault-ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 64-bit ABI uses registers (RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8 and R9) instead of the stack for argument passing. So the code should be:

```
movl %2,%%rdi
movl %1,%%rsi
call printf
movq %0,%%rax
```

Comment: Can't I use the stack to pass arguments? Are registers the only way to pass arguments on X64 ABI?

Comment: Every function using the 64-bit ABI expect to find the arguments in these registers (and basically ignore what's on the stack). Things get more complicated then the registers are not enough to hold the arguments. And if you write your own functions (in asm) you can of course use your own custom ABI if you want to.

Comment: My fuction (let's call it ```x```) gets called with 6 arguments in the registers. I'd like to call <some other function> before doing stuff with those 6 arguments. Do I need to store the 6 arguments? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, you have to store them. Either in local variables (the stack frame), global (thread unsafe) variables or the registers guaranteed to be preserved (RBX, RBP, R12, R13, R14 and R15). If you use these registers you are of course responsible for restoring them yourself before your function returns.

Comment: I'd go for the stack option. What should I do? just push-ing the registers I want to save and then pop-ing them when I want to restore them? Like ```push %%rsi;  some asm;  pop %%rsi```  ?

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but why isn't the code from your solution working on x86? (Replacing movq with movl, of course, and using ebx and ecx for the first and second register for arguments and eax for the result)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is relative to 64bit EABI. You can find some information on that [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265970/c-to-assembly-call-convention-32bit-vs-64bit).

Comment: Wouldn't that apply only if I was using registers? I mean, I'm push-ing my args, so iirc I shouldn't worry about registers. Please correct me if I'm wrong