# C format string vulnerability: How many bytes does %x read from the stack?

Tags: c, linux, 32-bit, format-string

my doubt is the following:
assuming Ubuntu 14.04 32bit and x_86 intel atom cpu how many bytes does the format %x read from stack?
I know that I can read what's in the stack by using:

```
formatstring="%x";
printf(formatstring);
```

As I put more `%x` in the formatstring, more data are read from the stack.
Since `%x` takes `4 bytes`, every `%x` should read `4 bytes` from the stack, so for example if the 1st `%x` read what's written at the address `0x0` the `2nd` will read what's at address `0x4` and so on.. (obviously the numbers are just for me to make the explanation easier). Is this assumption correct? It seems not since when I tried in an exercise to calculate the address of a var doing  `known_address + (numberof %x untill_the_var_value_is_printed )* 4` I found a wrong address.

Comment: Probably none, it would typically use a register

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: C knows nothing about stacks.  (Indeed, `register` keyword notwithstanding, it knows nothing about registers, either.)  Your code exhibits undefined behavior because there are insufficient arguments for the format.  Anything could happen.  You can study the behavior of a particular version of a particular implementation, but you cannot generalize that.  And as for me, I don't find studying manifestations of undefined behavior very intersting.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm doing an system security course on my 2nd of my MSc and we are looking at format string vulnerability and in this case using %x it actually prints 4 bytes from the stack

Comment: Typically the first few arguments are passed in [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), not the stack

Comment: From the manual:: `o, u, x, X
              The unsigned int argument is converted to  unsigned  octal  (o),
              unsigned  decimal  (u),  or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) ` --- so %x expects an unsigned int.

Comment: @mik1904, maybe in your case it does print 4 bytes from the stack, and in that case I guess you have then answered your own question.  Anyway, if you want to pose a question about a particular C implementation then it is incumbent on you to *specify the implementation*.  I'll not help you with such a question, but perhaps someone else will.

Comment: @M.M Does it typically use registers for variadic functions like `printf`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, [see here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301201/calling-printf-from-inline-asm-x64)

Comment: The OP specifies 32-bit Linux.  It doesn't specify a processor architecture, but doesn't Linux on ia32 typically use cdecl, in which all parameters are passed on the stack?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: For one who is studying software security, the manifestations of undefined behaviour are *very* interesting.  If one wants to abuse a software bug to get RCE, or if one wants to implement a migitation that makes it more difficult to do so, then one needs to understand what actually happens on various platforms when undefined behaviour is invoked.  However, you are correct that the OP should have been more precise about what platform it is using.  Since it it outside of the semantics of C, this sort of question might be more appropriate on https://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user3553031: "32 bit Linux" covers many very different architectures already. Including: x86, multiple ARM-versions, PPC, MIPS, SuperH to state the most common. All have very different ABIs, the RISC often use registers for the first arguments. The question is far too broad.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the C standard is concerned, the question is not meaningful.

A `%x` format specifier requires a corresponding argument of type `unsigned int`. (`unsigned int` and `int` are more or less interchangeable as arguments, as long as the value is within the representable range of both types.)  The standard doesn't explicitly say so, but it doesn't define the behavior.

*If* a particular compiler generates code that passes `unsigned int` arguments to variadic functions on the *stack* (a term the C standard doesn't use), then `printf` might read `sizeof (unsigned int)` bytes from the stack for each `%x` specifier. On other implementations, it might attempt to read arguments from registers, or from somewhere else. Also, `sizeof (unsigned int)` can vary from one implementation to another. In principle, it could even vary with compile-time optimization levels.

If you want to know about how something like `printf("%x")` will actually behave, you'll need to specify the particular implementation you're using, both the target OS and hardware and the compiler you're using. "32-bit Linux" is not nearly specific enough. Since C implementations are not required to document this, it might be difficult to get the details.